# Resources to learn how to manage tabular data (from BLAST+6 format ) using Bash and/or Biopython

Tags: python, bash, tabular, biopython, blast

I am running BLAST and would like to manipulate the output from using BLAST+6 format.

For example, I would like to take the E-value, query coverage, and identity for each hit and then plug them into an equation that weighs all three into a single "score". I would then like to take all scores and place them into a table so I can sort each hit by decreasing "score".

I would also like to generate an ORF for each BLAST hit on the database and add them to their corresponding place in the table.

Can someone point any resources/keywords I can search to learn about how to manipulate tabular data?

Example:

```
blastn  -query genes.fasta  -subject genome.fasta  -outfmt "6 qseqid pident qcovs  evalue"
```

Output:

```
    qseqid pident qcovs evalue   
0   moaC     100.00    0.0       161.0      
1   moaC     99.38     1.0       161.0
```

I would like to take values from each column and use them as variables in an equation, then print that value in the corresponding row. I will be using a bash script or BioPython for BLAST, so I would like to make the data manipulation as part of that

Rather than a solution to this example, I would like to see if there's a resource where I can learn about this topic (up until this point I would use spreadsheet programs to manipulate tabular data)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include an example of BLAST+6 format? Your question notes what it contains but I'd like to see how it's formatted. That will make it easier to think of how to manipulate it

Comment: Sure thing just did

Comment: Thanks. There are a lot of ways you could do this. One way would be to save the blast output in a text file, print/cut/copy the values columns to a new file, have a bash script to do the simple math to weight the values in a for loop by each row of the values columns, and cat/outputs those weighted values to a new file where you have previously placed the qseqid or whatever you need to identify which values go where. If one way doesn't work, try another - there's many ways to do this, and google/look up on stack overflow how to do each particular step, to teach yourself. Good luck!

Comment: awk can be useful for tasks that require calculations based on several columns. A simple example how it can be used: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277537/389227

Comment: Note that while you're getting good answers on this question, *in general*, requests for off-site resources like learning materials are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow; see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Likewise for tool-selection questions in general (the long history behind that policy is that when such questions were widely welcome, they led to flame wars, opinion-based answers, and questions with answers for which there was no objective way to say one was more correct than another).

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind. Since I am just learning about this I wanted to ask for direction without outright asking others to solve my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For working with tabular data, I really recommend [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

First you want to convert your output to a [`pandas DataFrame`](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-dataframe-a-lightweight-intro-680e3a212b96), which is a data structure that is well suited to store data that comes in tabular form.

For this example I'm using `tblastn` and the example files [`four_human_proteins.fasta`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peterjc/galaxy_blast/master/test-data/four_human_proteins.fasta) and [`rhodopsin_nucs.fasta`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peterjc/galaxy_blast/master/test-data/rhodopsin_nucs.fasta).

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline
>>> cline = NcbiblastnCommandline(cmd='/path/to/BLAST+/2.8.1/bin/tblastn', 
                          query='four_human_proteins.fasta', 
                          subject='rhodopsin_nucs.fasta', 
                          evalue='1e-10',
                          outfmt='"6 qseqid pident qcovs evalue"')
>>> print(cline)
/path/to/BLAST+/2.8.1/bin/tblastn -outfmt "6 qseqid pident qcovs evalue" -query four_human_proteins.fasta -evalue 1e-10 -subject rhodopsin_nucs.fasta

>>> blast_output = cline()[0].strip()
>>> print(blast_output) 
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.552  100 0.0
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    93.391  100 0.0
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    95.092  94  0.0
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    84.795  98  0.0
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    82.164  98  0.0
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.396  89  2.65e-67
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    92.308  89  7.50e-36
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    93.220  89  1.81e-32
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.296  89  6.37e-32
sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    88.462  89  4.64e-12


>>> headers = ['qseqid', 'pident', 'qcovs', 'evalue']
>>> rows = [line.split() for line in blast_output.splitlines()]    
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
>>> print(df)
    qseqid  pident  qcovs   evalue
0   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.552  100     0.0
1   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    93.391  100     0.0
2   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    95.092  94  0.0
3   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    84.795  98  0.0
4   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    82.164  98  0.0
5   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.396  89  2.65e-67
6   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    92.308  89  7.50e-36
7   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    93.220  89  1.81e-32
8   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.296  89  6.37e-32
9   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    88.462  89  4.64e-12
```

First we need to tell `pandas` which columns contain `float`s.

```
>>> convert = {'pident': float, 
              'qcovs': float, 
              'evalue': float,
              'qseqid': str}
>>> df = df.astype(convert)
```

Now can now easily perform columnwise operations on this DataFrame `df`.
Define your score function and add the result as an extra column:

```
>>> df['score'] = df['qcovs'] / df['pident']  # adapt to your own needs
>>> print(df)
    qseqid  pident  qcovs   evalue  score
0   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.552  100.0   0.000000e+00    1.035711
1   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    93.391  100.0   0.000000e+00    1.070767
2   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    95.092  94.0    0.000000e+00    0.988516
3   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    84.795  98.0    0.000000e+00    1.155729
4   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    82.164  98.0    0.000000e+00    1.192736
5   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.396  89.0    2.650000e-67    0.923275
6   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    92.308  89.0    7.500000e-36    0.964163
7   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    93.220  89.0    1.810000e-32    0.954731
8   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.296  89.0    6.370000e-32    0.924234
9   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    88.462  89.0    4.640000e-12    1.006082
```

And you can easily sort the DataFrame by this `score` column

```
>>> df.sort_values(['score'], inplace=True)
>>> print(df)
    qseqid  pident  qcovs   evalue  score
5   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.396  89.0    2.650000e-67    0.923275
8   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.296  89.0    6.370000e-32    0.924234
7   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    93.220  89.0    1.810000e-32    0.954731
6   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    92.308  89.0    7.500000e-36    0.964163
2   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    95.092  94.0    0.000000e+00    0.988516
9   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    88.462  89.0    4.640000e-12    1.006082
0   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    96.552  100.0   0.000000e+00    1.035711
1   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    93.391  100.0   0.000000e+00    1.070767
3   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    84.795  98.0    0.000000e+00    1.155729
4   sp|P08100|OPSD_HUMAN    82.164  98.0    0.000000e+00    1.192736
```